# Patent Authorship

Tags: us20020040938

In reference to the patent: [US20020040938](https://www.google.com/patents/US20020040938)

Hello, I do not know how to deal when I found that this patent is using my original idea and my Computations without I being a co-author of the patent. I found the patent very late and then I contact one of the Authors with whom I collaborated on the indenture by mail i did not hear from him although on other occasions I do.

Please advice what else I can do so that my name is added as a co-author of this patent.

Thank you very much in advance,

Sincerely,

Boyko Tchavdarov, Ph.D.

Comment: If it is duplicate please forward your answer. I have not receive an answer of my question.

Comment: i apologize.  I did not see the top of this form where a link to the answer was provided. From what I have understood I have to submit on my own as my work was conducted as Independent Researcher 1)  to 5) forms to the USPTO Office.  
Thank you.

Comment: In a bit similar situation for another patents:  A Company with whom I used to work issued patents on my ideas without my name after I started working for another Company. Should I submit a claim my name to be included in those patents by my own as Independent Researcher or that should be done by the Company i am working at present?

Comment: with cc: to @ihtkwot